# AsyncTask and subclassing

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I'm getting the following issue while subclassing AsyncTask:

```
-compile:
    [javac] Compiling 6 source files to C:\DEV\MyProject\bin\classes
    [javac] C:\DEV\MyProject\src\org\example\myproject\MainActivity.java:234: error:
method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
    [javac]     @Override
    [javac]     ^
    [javac] C:\DEV\MyProject\src\org\example\myproject\MainActivity.java:286: error:
method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
    [javac]     @Override
    [javac]     ^
    [javac] 2 errors
```

My code (doInBackground is also here yet the compiler doesn't complain):

```
protected class DoThingsTask extends AsyncTask
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... params)
    {
        // things
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute(Void... params)
    {
        super.onPreExecute();
        // ... do things
        Log.i(TAG, "AsyncTask: pre-execution done");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void... result)
    {
        Log.i(TAG, "AsyncTask: PostExecution start");
        // .... do other things
        Log.d(TAG, "AsyncTask PostExecution done");
    }
```

So the compiler is complaining about the `@Override` annotation. If I remove the annotations, it compiles fine but does not call `onPreExecute` nor `onPostExecute`. I have no idea why it's got an issue.

I'm using the command line here - so I'm calling `ant clean` every time.

Ideas appreciated!

Comment: How are you declaring the `AsyncTask` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your parameters are wrong.  OnPreExecute takes no parameters.  onPostExecute takes a single parameter of type Result (where result is any single type you choose).  It does not take variable parameters.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that your AsyncTask Class has different parameter types specified, such as :

```
private class Example extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
     @Override 
     protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
       //this is correct @Override, the doInBackground has the same variable type of String
     }

     @Override
     protected void onPostExecute(Void... params) {
       //this is Wrong @Override, the Post result should be String
       //as shown by <String, Void, String>
       //the correct one should be :
       //@Override
       //protected String onPostExecute (String...params) {
       //.....
       //.....}
     }
}
```

also, as [Gabe Sechan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1631193/gabe-sechan) pointed out, onPreExecute does not take any parameters, so it cannot be overridden, try modifying it to this one :

```
@Override
protected void onPreExecute()
{
    super.onPreExecute();
    // ... do things
    Log.i(TAG, "AsyncTask: pre-execution done");
}
```

**EDIT** , you declared your asyncTask incorrectly, you should specify the parameter of the asnyctask as follows :

`private class Example extends AsyncTask<InputType, ProgressType, ResultType>`

if you want make it void, use `Void` as the parameter type.

Good Luck ^^

Answer (score 0):

The class you are deriving from AsyncTask should have red squigly line underneath it for error. If you press...

Windows:
`Ctrl + 1`

Mac:
`Command + 1`

to pull up quick fix (or just hover over red squigly)

It should say "Add unimplemented methods" and do the heavy lifting for you. If onPreExecute and onPostExecute doesnt implement, right click the class and hit source -> Override / Implement methods and find the ones you are looking for.
`